# Is there a better way to calculate the bootstrap container gutter as a margin?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a navbar that has a background that is flush with the right side of the page but doesn't extend the whole width of the page. I also want the navigation links to line up with the content below it which will be in a container.

Here is an example: http://www.bootply.com/7KTnoOkEJD

Here is the CSS I used:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li:last-child {
  margin-right: calc((100vw - 765px) / 2);
  }
  .navbar-nav>li:last-child a {
  padding-right:0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav>li:last-child {
  margin-right: calc((100vw - 985px) / 2);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-nav>li:last-child {
  margin-right: calc((100vw - 1185px) / 2);
  }
}
```

I got the pixel numbers in the calc()s from the width of .container in bootstrap.css.

Is this bad code or is there a better way to accomplish this?

I was originally going to ask how to accomplish this but while writing the bootply I figured it out and decided it might still be a good question to ask here.

Comment: so you don't want the blue bar after the red line ? In both view ??

Comment: I should have explained the red line - It was just a guide I was using and it seemed useful to leave in. I want everything to look like it does but I don't want the red line.